# How to make swiper-helm to use helm layout?

Tags: helm, helm-selection, swiper, swiper-helm

I set this in helm

```
(setq helm-split-window-in-side-p nil)
```

This forces helm to use selected window for helm session like this(When point is in right split, helm buffer popped in left split only).

[image]

Now when I use `swiper-helm`, it doesn't honor this. It will open helm session in different split.

How can I make swiper-helm and all other packages which use helm as frontend (like helm-recent-dirs, helm-github-stars), to use custom helm config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to customize `swiper-helm-display-function`.  In `swiper-helm`, `helm-display-function` is let-bound to `swiper-helm-display-function`.

Should be as simple as:

```cl
(setq swiper-helm-display-function 'helm-default-display-buffer)
```

As for other commands that you asked about, it's likely that they bind `helm-display-function` as well.  Just examine their code and change the corresponding defcustom.

Comment: I use ~20 of helm packages. I dont want to check each and every function and customize it. I am wondering if there is a generic way to make all such package conform to custom layout?

Comment: There isn't. ~20 helm packages are very losely related by helm. They can have different authors with different ideas for implementing the window-splitting behavior.